# Umbraco Cannot View Admin Panel After Migrate From Localhost to Webhost

Tags: asp.net, umbraco

I already setup umbraco in my localhost. And it's works perfectly.

I uploaded all the files to webhost.

Also, I migrated the database from localhost to webhost using SQL Server Import & Export Data Wizard (because I use SQL Server 2014 instead of SQL CE)

Ok, so it's working perfectly in front end...

But whenever I access to admin panel (http://mywebsiteexample.com/umbraco),
there will be a login box...

so after I fill up the login box and click login, the screen shows nothing..

Why?

could someone please help me?
I use the freehosting at http://www.somee.com

Comment: Are there any errors in the browser's console? Also look in the network tab for hints

Comment: try clearing your browser cache and cookies - especially the cookies.  also what happens if you try a different browser?

Comment: @Eyescream 
this is the error: Password fields present on an insecure (http://) page. This is a security risk that allows user login credentials to be stolen.

Comment: @RobertFoster same problem on another browser

Comment: Are the permissions for the user that runs the app pool set right on the new database? And also check the connection string in the web config

Comment: @Eyescream this is my connection string in Web.Config 
<add name="umbracoDbDSN" connectionString="workstation id=webs-i.mssql.somee.com;packet size=4096;user id=my_id;pwd=mypassword;data source=webs-i.mssql.somee.com;persist security info=False;initial catalog=webs-i" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

Comment: My connection string is <add name="umbracoDbDSN" connectionString="Server=192.168.10.110\sqlexpress;Database=YOURDB;User Id=sa;Password=YOURPASSWORD;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

Comment: i;m sorry the error is actually:  Error: Template must have exactly one root element.

Comment: could someone please help me?
I use the freehosting at http://www.somee.com

Answer (score 0):

You might have only copied the schema and forgotten the data from the database.
I believe running the installer will generate the content based on the XML, if I'm correct.

Try this by going to: www.website.com/install